# Splunk search doesn't match CSV lookup file

Tags: splunk

In Splunk I need to match search results client IP list with an input lookup CSV file `knownip.csv`. I want the results, which didn't match with CSV file.

**Step 1.** Created list of verified known IP as a CSV file saved in my local system

**Step 2.** Navigated **Manager > Lookups > Add New > Lookup Table File**

**Step 3.** Uploaded my file and named it `KnownIP.csv`. Now under **Manager > Lookups > Add New > Lookup Definition** I have `name=clientIP`, `lookup-file=KnownIP.csv`.

**Step 4.** Now I defined my search query like this:

```
search NOT[|inputlookup Lookupfile | fields Name ] index=* serverName>servername113
    | rex field=clientIP "(?<clientIP>\d+.\d+.\d+)"
    | stats count by clientIP
    | search NOT [|inputlookup append=t KnownIP.csv|fields clientIP]
```

As I noted, I need help getting this search to match the CSV file.

Comment: please share your code and format the question

Comment: Hi Raid i have added the code

Comment: I have used rex to match first two section with csv file then result should come with full IP but it is not matching properly

Comment: index=* serverName>servername113 | rex field=clientIP "(?\d+.\d+.\d+)"| stats count by clientIP |search NOT [|inputlookup append=t KnownIP.csv|fields clientIP

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do what you're asking for

The first is to use the lookup table as a filter in your initial search, like this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp NOT [|inputlookup mylookup | fields ip]
```

Or, do a `lookup`, and keep all the entries that have a null value in the lookup's other field ... like this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp
| lookup mylookup ip OUTPUT otherfield AS filterfield
| where isnull(filterfield)
```